# Testcafe works when it should not

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, automated-tests, testcafe

First thanks to anyone who can help with this it's greatly appreciated.

As you can see by the title this is a very weird occurrence.  I do a lot of work with testcafe and can't really explain this.

The scenario is at my company we raise instances in AWS put our product on the instance then run the automation.  These instances are automatically torn down in around 3 hours so I can't really post an instance example as it will tear down.  When I try to go to the instance I get stuck with a spinner at the login page.  I tried firefox, chrome, chromium, safari, incognito, tor, etc... They all get stuck at this spinner, in fact, this happens to everyone in the company.

For some reason when I run some tests via testcafe on my computer using chrome on this instance it gets past this spinner, logs in, then just resumes tests like nothing is wrong.  I have tried using localhost as the host, different ports, skip js errors, and other flags.  I am updated to the latest version of testcafe.  My theory is that it has something to do with the proxy server that testcafe launches (just a guess).  I tried online proxy servers and even made a local proxy server but still, none can get past this spinner.

I'm pretty sure more info would be needed to help out on this I'm just not sure what to add.  If any tips or logs to add please let me know.

**UPDATE:**
I tried a few more online proxy site and found one that worked (performed in the same behavior as testcafe). I believe at this point i can prove that its related to the proxy server. Now with that proved, im assuming there is no way to get around this issue right (meaning have testcafe fail)?

Comment: The proxy we are using is [hammerhead](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead).
Try using it separately, without TestCafe, to access the instance. To do this, follow the instructions from readme.md. This will help you test your hypothesis.

Comment: Hey thanks!  I tried a few more online proxy sites today and found one that worked (performed in the same behavior as testcafe).  I believe at this point i can prove that its related to the proxy server.  Now with that proved, im assuming there is no way to get around this issue right (have testcafe fail)?

Comment: Since website behavior with and without TestCafe differs, I suggest you [create an issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md) in the TestCafe GitHub repository. Please share a project example where this problem is reproducible.

Comment: Thanks I have opened a ticket with them as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened with testcafe and they have reported its a bug: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6055